# Cloud with shared memory

Tags: memory, cloud

do you know any if any well known clouds, e.g. Amazon, Azure, Google App Engine that has feature of shared memory? E.g. you can access data fast (from memory) and those are automatically synchronized with other nodes (machines...whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite shared memory, but Windows Azure has a Cache you can use. It's configurable from 128MB to 4GB, and exists outside of a specific deployment, letting you share cache content across instances, deployments, even on-premises applications.

More info on Cache is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697522.aspx).